# jQuery highlight search term based on URL 

Tags: jquery, regex, url, search, highlight

I am testing out the plugin "[searchHighlight](http://www.jquery.info/spip.php?article50)" to highlight search terms on our Search page when one searches for a keywords. The problem is that it only reads the referral URL and I do not know how to modify this so it only reads the current URL that your on instead of the referral.

I.e.

1. I use our search box from my home page
2. I search for 'glass door'
3. Results come up on the search page but no highlighting
4. I click a product with the words 'glass' or 'door' in it
5. On the product page it highlights the words I searched for ('glass' + 'door')

Example URL Searched: http://tsqja.deznp.servertrust.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=glass+door&x=0&y=0

From the example I tried to give above you can see it is highlighting based off the Referral URL Keywords. I want it to use the actual search results.  Given regex this is my search results page:

```
[/^http:\/\/(tsqja\.)?deznp\.servertrust/i,/Search=([^&]+)/i]
```

Anyone know how this can be achieved? Get highlighted search terms based off the above regex via jQuery preferably?

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve the problem, but it's really quite easy to get the query results of a page.  You can get the current `?something=blah` part of a url with `location.search`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `keys` configuration option to set the highlighting up manually on the search page. You could use a small script to get the search term from the url using a regex, then pass the configuration into SearchHighlight:

```
// Get the keys from the URL using a regex
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript
...

// Put the keys into the options
var options = {keys: "Glass Door"}
jQuery(document).SearchHighlight(options);
```

Using the `keys` option completely disables the referrer checking.

Comment: I have tried this and perhaps I need to revisit. I just need to create a function to grab the search term and throw it into 'keys'.  Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you can see how it works (after you have found the terms) at their [demo page](http://www.jquery.info/scripts/SearchHighlight/demo_en.html).

There should be some functions to grab the search term from the [page I included in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

Try the [SearchHighlight](http://www.jquery.info/spip.php?article50) plugin for jQuery. They have a demo page [here](http://www.jquery.info/scripts/SearchHighlight/demo_en.html)

Comment: I've been using this, however it only reads the Referral.  If I could modify the plugin to use only the URL I specify and NOT use the referral it would be perfect.

Comment: I have also found this other [plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)..seems really interesting

Comment: The debug_referrer option got me closer but again, the search results will be ON the search page.  And I cannot specify every page on my site as a referrer...or can I?

Comment: I am not sure you can and anyway they just intended it for debug so this is not the best solution on production i think. Give a try to http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, again it's not exactly *the best* solution...... but you could use this:

```
if(document.referrer !== location.href) location.reload()
```

That will reload the page if the current url is not the referrer.  This will only run once provided the url is not constantly changed on page load.